# Why my firebase not adding from project structure?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am trying to add Firebase from project structure, but dependencies and permissions are not adding.
Should I have to add them manually every time?

Comment: if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud section you are looking for is not being displayed on newer versions of Android Studio (+2.2 i guess).
You will have to add them manually, but luckly, it's quite simple :)

On a "recent" Google Developer's video called [Getting started with Firebase and Android - Firecasts #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1rlT5KQ0yE), they do show this option, but the Android Studio version is 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Well! I did not set the SDK at a right location. There was a space in folder name like "Program Files" where I put the SDK. I change the location of SDK and now its working fine.
Thank you All for your help.